# Codeigniter Comment Reply System

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CI.

Now i am try to develop the comment system with reply option.

So far i have developed the insert comment and reply comment.

But i don't know how to fetch reply comments under the main comment.

Please help me.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursive function! For that you will need to do something like this:

1. Get the first comment.
2. Call the recursive function. The ID of the comment must be passed as an argument.
3. The function must get the comments & call itself in order to get all the comments.

A pseudo-code of this schema will be:

```
myComment = getComment();
recursiveComments(myComment);

function recursiveComments(currentComment){
  print(currentComment);
  replies = getReplies(currentComment['idComment']);
  foreach(replies as reply){
     recursiveComments(reply);
  }
}
```

In the pseudo-code, I'm assuming that you get a row_array with the getComment() function & that this comment is the "head" of all the comments, like the initial post. 
After that, I call the recursive function which gets all the replies & sub-replies for each comment. Note the I fetch a single reply in each call to the function.

Hope this gives you an idea! (=